# Not able to get data from edittext inside custom adapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

Here i am facing a very weird problem while trying to get data from `EditText` in  a `CustomAdapter`. I have gone through some similar questions in SO but cant find the solution. `Logcat` once showed this `Exception` **gettextbeforecursor on inactive inputconnection and gettextaftercursor on inactive inputconnection **. When the `EditText` is `focused` the `softinput` keyboard appears and i am able to write in it but i am not able to get the value that has been inserted inside the `Edittext`. I am pasting below my `Custom Adapter`.

**MenuCardAdapter.java**

```
public class MenuCardAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemsClass> {

Context activity;
ArrayList<ItemsClass> values = new ArrayList<ItemsClass>();
TextView main_name, item_price;
Button cartBtn;
EditText quantity;
Restaurant_Sql res_sql;
ItemsClass items;
ImageView imageView;
String value;

public MenuCardAdapter(Context activity, int detailListview,
        ArrayList<ItemsClass> values) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(activity, detailListview, values);
    this.activity = activity;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
    // .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_menu_items, null);

    res_sql = new Restaurant_Sql(activity);
    res_sql.Open();
    items = values.get(position);

    main_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label_main);
    cartBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cartBtn);
    quantity = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantity_value);

    item_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_price_home);
    imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_home);
    main_name.setText(items.getItemName());
    item_price.setText(items.getItemPrice() + "/-");

    if (items.getItemName().equals("Soup")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.soup);
    }
    if (items.getItemName().equals("Dhosa")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dhosa);
    }

    if (items.getItemName().equals("Continental")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.continental);
    }

    if (items.getItemName().equals("Mutter Panner")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.punjabi);
    }

    if (items.getItemName().equals("Hakka Noodles")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.chinese);
    }

    if (items.getItemName().equals("Butterscotch")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icream);
    }

    cartBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(activity, quantity.getText().toString().trim(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return convertView;
} 
    }
```

**Edit**

Once i got this in the stacktrace

`W/IInputConnectionWrapper(8152): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(8152): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(8152): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(8152): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(8152): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(8152): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(8152): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(8152): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(8152): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection`

if anybody can help ???

Comment: Have you tried using ViewHolder pattern and recycling views?

Comment: Are you using standard keyboard or do you have a custom one? Btw, i would recommend first solving this issue, and maybe after that thinking about using VHP

Comment: using the standard keyboard

Comment: I am not seeing any code where u using view recycling. U must use that

Comment: What context are you using in constructor?

Comment: let me try using recycling views

Comment: Btw is there any reason you are storing views as fields? AFAIK this should never happen in adapter.

Comment: Try to initialize a string and check it in LogCat first. Then load it in Toast

Comment: @iBecar when you have custom adapter, you do. You have to give id of custom layout views.

Comment: yes dhaval i have tried that but getting nothing inside the LogCat

Comment: Are you sure you've initialized the same Id of editText you're getting the text from? If yes, then Remove .trim() and try. I am going through your code, and will try to help you.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers , i have solved the problem by recycling views , ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know its too late to answer, but i find it useful for others facing the same problem,

as per the comments initially i solved the problem by using the `ViewHolder` pattern. That didnt only solved the problem but also made `view` scrolling smoother. More reference can be found here [ViewHolder Reference](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)

As an better solution i would propose to use `RecylcerView`.

`RecyclerView` by default provides `View` **Recycling** more reference can be found here :

[RecyclerView Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)

Hope this helps others facing the same issue. Thanks